# How to correctly customize third party react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I am beginner in React, using the components from http://www.material-ui.com/ Through npm.

I need to make considerable changes to the functionality of some of these third party components, but am not sure how to go about it in a way which will:

1. support future updates to material-ui.
2. Will allow me to create new props and states.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have to make "considerable changes", I think the best thing you can do is take the code from their github and implement them in your own way.

Otherwise you are going to spend a lot of time trying to make them work the way you want
(at least that's what happened to me!).

Comment: This means giving up on future releases, no?

Comment: yep, that is the downside.